# sql retrieve related records based on second table

Tags: sql, join

I know the basics of SQL, but for a project I need to do the following and I'm blocked.
I have two tables:

Person

```
ID | NAME
```

and Project

```
ID | PersonID | ProjectID
```

In the Project table could be that the same ProjectID is in 4 records once for each person.
I want a list with all the names from Person and all the names they have worked together in a Project.

So if I have a certain person (i.e Id 73571), I have come up to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person.name 
FROM person INNER JOIN project on person.id=project.personid
WHERE project.id IN (
    SELECT id FROM project WHERE id=73571) 
ORDER BY person.name;
```

How can I do this to work for all records of Person table?

Comment: Could you provide some example output? What should the output look like when both a project has many people and a person has many projects?

Comment: Something like:
Person1 - Coworker1
Person1 - Coworker2
Person2 - ...

Comment: I guess that `WHERE id=73571` should be `WHERE personid=73571`

Comment: yes you are right copy mistake. This part works ok. I need an idea on how to get the same result but for every personid not only 73571.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I use MySQL on a linux pc through terminal.

Comment: @user2437190 - Does [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7ae6/2) represent your data?

Comment: yes and it could be also that there are multiple projects for the same person. But in general this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea.  How about a name from person and a comma delimited list of all persons they have worked with?  Here is the syntax in MySQL:

```
SELECT pp.p1, pp.p1.name, group_concat(distinct p2.name)
FROM (select p1.id as p1, p1.name as p1name, p2.id as p2, p2.name as p2name
      from person p1 cross join
           person p2
      where p1.id <> p2.id
     ) pp join
     project pr1
     on pr1.personid = pp.p1 join
     project pr2
     on pr2.personid = pp.p2 and
        pr2.id = pr1.id
group by pp.p1, pp.p1name;
```

The idea starts with a master list of all pairs of people.  It then joins in all the projects that the first person is on, and all the matching projects for the second person.  These are concatenated together, using `group concat`.

If you are happy with lists of the pairs, here is an example that runs in SQL Server:

```
with person as (
      select 1 as id, 'a' as name union all
      select 2, 'b' union all
      select 3, 'c' union all
      select 4, 'd' union all
      select 5, 'e'
     ),
     project as (
      select 1 as id, 1 as personid union all
      select 1 as id, 2 as personid union all
      select 1 as id, 3 union all
      select 2, 4 union all
      select 2, 5 union all
      select 3, 1 union all
      select 3, 5
     )
SELECT distinct pp.p1name, pp.p2name
FROM (select p1.id as p1, p1.name as p1name, p2.id as p2, p2.name as p2name
      from person p1 cross join
           person p2
      where p1.id <> p2.id
     ) pp join
     project pr1
     on pr1.personid = pp.p1 join
     project pr2
     on pr2.personid = pp.p2 and
        pr2.id = pr1.id;
```

EDIT:

Here is another way of thinking about the problem (if my interpretation is correct).  I'm not sure why I didn't go in this direction first.  You are looking for all (distinct)  pairs of people who worked together on a project.  Getting pairs from such a list is a self join.  This leads to the following query:

```
SELECT distinct p1.name, p2.name
FROM project pr1 join
     project pr2
     on pr1.id = pr2.id and
        pr1.personid <> pr2.personid join
     person p1
     on pr1.personid = p1.id join
     person p2
     on pr2.personid = p2.id;
```

(You can add the `group_concat()` if you like to put rows into a comma-separated list.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. It will take me a while to try it, and i will post.

Comment: it's getting long and I guess it will take longer. my tables have a few hundred thousand rows.

Comment: wow this works great, so is @Ochi 's i guess. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

simple query

```
select pro.projectid
       ,per.name
       ,trim(BOTH ',' FROM replace(GROUP_CONCAT(per.name SEPARATOR ','), per.name, '')) as coworkers
from person as per,
     project as pro
where per.id = pro.personid
group by pro.projectid

projectid      name         coworkers
1              person1      person2,person3,person4
2              person2      person4
3              person3      person4,person5

-- for pairs
  SELECT pro.projectid, per.name, co.name
    FROM project pro
         LEFT JOIN project pro2 on (pro.projectid = pro2.projectid and pro.personid <> pro2.personid)
         LEFT JOIN person per on pro.personid = per.id
         LEFT JOIN person co on pro2.personid = co.id
ORDER BY pro.projectid ASC, per.name ASC, co.name ASC
```

Comment: this works smoothly and fast. how can I make the result like person1-coworker1, person1-coworker2, each in different row?

Comment: new version for pairs - oh... just saw it: it's same as @gordon's :)